# How to perform a compound query against to many relationships in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I am looking for some assistance in understanding NSPredicates and how to query CoreData. Here is what I have:

I have two entities: 1. Capture that represents a "capture" of some data and it has a to many relationship to 2. Identity tags.

I am looking to essentially get a Set of "Identity" tags from a particular Set of "Captures". i.e. I want to know all the unique identities of name 'X' for captures that are also tagged with an id of Int 'y'.

In swift I would model this like:

```
let captures: [Capture]
let identities = captures.flatmap({ $0.identities }).filter({ $0.id == "y" })
let uniqueIdentitiesOfParticularType: Set<Identity> = Set(identities.flatMap({ $0.name })
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, definitely start with the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-CJBDBHCB), which covers more of this in detail. See particularly "Using Predicates with Core Data."

Your solution is likely something along these lines if you wanted to be a bit careful about faulting:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Capture")
let id = "y"
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id)
let identities = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as NSArray
let names = identities.valueForKeyPath("@distinctUnionOfObjects.name")
```

Note that iOS 10 adds better bridges for this to Swift (you may not need `as NSArray`), but I haven't really explored them yet.

For more on `@distinctUnionOfObjects` and its friends, see [Collection Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE).

Comment: Thanks Rob! This got me on the right track. I guess I thought there might be a better way to tell CoreData to fetch these objects in one go thus the reason I was trying to figure out how to make NSPredicates do all the work.

Comment: Just remember that Core Data is not a database. It's purpose isn't arbitrary record queries. It's an object persistence engine. It's purpose is maintaining a consistent object graph. "Fetching" is just an implementation detail because the data set may not all fit in memory. The main power of Core Data is in helping your navigate a complex system of relationships rather than "querying rows." If you have many independent records without many fixed relationships, I often find a database to be the better tool.

Comment: I appreciate that... for this little project that I am working on I have a data set that is stored in JSON locally. CoreData just provided a nice way to serialize this data into appropriate objects, maintain how they relate to each other, and interact with them. I think in exploring this solution I maybe was trying to over-engineer thinking there was a better way then looking at all the objects returned by the fetch.